# Разговорный или литературный стиль

Tags: стилистика

Проработав два месяца, у него возникли неприятности с начальником;
Приняв смену, водители направляются диспетчером на объекты;
Выступая на собрании, нужно говорить кратко и по делу;
Изучая проблемы транспорта, учеными получены интересные результаты;
Каждый раз, заканчивая работу, ему становилось тепло на душе.

Answer (score 3):

Лексически правильное тут только третье предложение. Остальные вообще построены неграмотно. Нужно, например: "После двух месяцев работы у него возникли неприятности с начальником".

Answer (score 2):

Грамматические ошибки в употреблении деепричастного оборота.Правильные 2, 3 предложения.Нарушение в употреблении основного и добавочного действий.
  Когда он проработал 2 месяца, у него возникли проблемы с начальником.
 Изучая проблемы транспорта, учёные получили интересные результаты.
 Каждый раз по окончании работы ему становилось тепло на душе.